# Find the adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

Choose one from he following list of inner products and then find the adjoint of:

$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & 2 \\
     -1 & 3
  \end{array} \right]
$$

When your inner prod cut is used on both its domain and target space.

a. The Euclidean dot product

b. The weighted inner product $\langle v,w\rangle=2v_1w_1+3v_1w_1$

I guess I don't really understand how to find the domain or target space of a matrix.

All I could find online was that the adjoint is the transpose of the cofactor matrix but I'm not sure how to calculate the cofactor matrix.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The cofactor version of adjoint is not what you need here. Adjoint has multiple meanings, but when an inner product is involved, its the thing that allows you to move an operator from one side of the inner product to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjoint with respect to the standard dot product is the transpose.

For the other dot product, first find its Gram matrix $B$:
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
\langle e_1,e_1\rangle & \langle e_1,e_2\rangle \\
\langle e_2,e_1\rangle & \langle e_2,e_2\rangle
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(I suppose the formula is $\langle v,w\rangle=2v_1w_1+3v_2w_2$).

The dot product can then be realized as
$$
\langle v,w\rangle=v^TBw
$$
The adjoint to $A$ is the unique matrix $A^*$ such that, for all $v,w$, we have
$$
\langle v,A^*w\rangle=\langle Av,w\rangle
$$
that is, in matrix terms
$$
v^TBA^*w=(Av)^TBw
$$
or, in other terms
$$
(v^TBA^*-v^TA^TB)w=0
$$
Since this must hold for every $w$, we have
$$
0=v^T(BA^*-A^TB)
$$
and finally, since this holds for all $v$,
$$
BA^*=A^TB
$$
which means
$$
A^*=B^{-1}A^TB
$$

Note that the formula holds also for the standard product, where the Gram matrix is the identity.

Comment: Oh I guess a lot of my confusion came from the fact that there must be a typo in the book where it should be 3v2w2 and not 3v1w1, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @MathMajor That wouldn't be an inner product; I thought the typo was yours, to be honest. It happens.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an inner product $<\cdot, \cdot>$, the adjoint of an operator $A$ is $A^*$ where $<Ax,y> = < x,A^*y>$ for any $x,y$.

For the dot product, $(Ax) \cdot y = (A x)^T y = x^T A^T y = x^T (A^T y) = x \cdot (A^T y)$ so the adjoint of $A$ is $A^T$.

Now, try the other inner product on your own.

Answer (score 1):

This matrix acts on a $2$-dimensional vector (so it has a $2$-dimensional domain) and the output is a $2$-dimensional vector (so it has a $2$-dimensional target space (also called codomain)). So, if you're working in real numbers $\Bbb{R}$ (which I imagine is the case here), the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the target space is $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Whenever you want to find the domain and target space of a matrix, reason as above.

Comment: since the OP's question refers to an inner product, I think he means the adjoint of the operator as explained in @Batman's answer, rather than the "usual" adjoint of a matrix.

Comment: @JohnC fair point. I've edited my answer accordingly